# How to unbind the php built-in server from a directory?

Tags: php, server, built-in, php-builtin-server

I created a local WordPress site and in XAMPP set it up with Virtual Hosts so the address *test-wp.dev* was the home adress. All was working fine and then for some reason I decided to turn off apache, leave mysql on and try the build in server.

So I navigated to *C:/xampp/htdocs/test/wordpress/* and ran `php -S localhost:8080`

It worked fine. However, today I went to go back to test-wp.dev using the Apache server and it keeps redirecting to *localhost:8080*. I don't want to use the built in server now. I want Apache.

Where do I "unbind this" or free up that port or whatever. I don't want to have to run the built in server for that folder anymore.

Thanks.

Windows 7
PHP 5.6